# How should we write team names?

Tags: discussion

A question I asked recently was [edited](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/1618/revisions) to replace the team names with their city, with the edit summary "added the actual team names".

What is the convention on writing in the names of teams?  I feel as if in the NFL it is normal for the cities and team names to be used interchangeably, although it is particularly ambiguous for "New York" (Giants or Jets?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you had used *only* the nicknames; I thought it was important that the actual names of the teams appear *somewhere* in the text, for the purpose of searchability.

If there is a chance of ambiguity, then I'm all for spelling it out clearly. But that doesn't have to be the case every time a team is referenced.

Comment: Having both somewhere in the text definitely makes sense; leaving the title as is achieved that.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that if we want to make edits to add the most clarity, we should use the full name of the team.  It's the most unambiguous way of representing it.

- "Green Bay Packers" instead of "Packers" or "Green Bay"
- "New York Jets" instead of "Jets" or "New York"
- "Arizona Cardinals" instead of "Cardinals" or "Arizona"